# Android Graphics Path() disappearing

Tags: android, graphics, path

I'm drawing a custom shape using the path method, but it performs differently than is displayed.

As displayed in the Layout: [image: expected]

On the device: [image: actual]

This only happens when the angle at the left vertex becomes too small. If I widened the shape, such that it became a regular diamond, the entire shape appears (regardless of size).

Here's the code:

```
final Path p = new Path();

p.moveTo(x, y);
p.lineTo(x - height / 16, y - 20);
p.lineTo(x - width / 3, y);
p.lineTo(x - height / 16, y + 20);

p.close();

canvas.drawPath(p, mThumbColorPaint);
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Could be a device bug. I've seen various device-dependent quirks in `Path` implementations.  What does the `Paint` look like?

Comment: What do you mean what does the `Paint` look like? I attached pictures.